# Ajax For HTML Generated From Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have html being generated from Javascript to create a list of items. I also need to call a Jquery Ajax call on each of those items but since it isn't in the html from the page ready I think that might be why the Ajax isn't called. When I click the submit button it tries to refresh the page so this shows that the prevent default isn't being run.

EDIT: spelling

What am i doing wrong here?

Javascript that generates HTML:

```
buildCollectionList()
    
    function buildCollectionList(){
        var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/collection_items_list/'
        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){
                for (var x in data){
                    var wrapper = document.getElementById(`collection_scroll${data[x].post}`)
                    
                    var product = wrapper.getAttribute('name')
                    //console.log(product)
                    wrapper.innerHTML = ''
                    

                    /*fetch(url)
                    .then((resp) => resp.json())
                    .then(function(data){
                        console.log('Data:', data)*/

                    var list = data
                    for (var i in list){

                        if ((list[i].saved == true) && (list[i].post == product)){
                            var item = `
                            <div class="collection_save_container">
                                <div class="collection_save_name">${list[i].parent_collection_name}</div>
                                        
                                    <form class="collection_save_form" action="" method="POST" id="${list[i].collection}" name="${list[i].post}">
                                                                            
                                        <button type="submit" class="collection_save_btn saved" id="save_btn ${list[i].collection} ${list[i].post}"><div class="saved_text ${list[i].collection}">Saved</div></button>
                                                                                            
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                        
                            </div>

                        `
                        wrapper.innerHTML += item
                        } else if (list[i].post == product){
                            var item = `
                            <div class="collection_save_container">
                                <div class="collection_save_name">${list[i].parent_collection_name}</div>
                                        
                                    <form class="collection_save_form" action="" method="POST" id="${list[i].collection}" name="${list[i].post}">
                                                                            
                                        <button type="submit" class="collection_save_btn" id="save_btn ${list[i].collection} ${list[i].post}"><div class="saved_text ${list[i].collection}">Save</div></button>
                                        
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                        
                            </div>
                        `
                        wrapper.innerHTML += item

                        }

                        
                        

                    }
                    //})
                }
            })
    }
```

Jquery Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            
    $('.collection_save_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        //const url = $(this).attr('action')
        const url = "{% url 'savepost' 0 1000 %}"
        const post_id = $(this).attr('name')
        const collection_id = $(this).attr('id')
        const text = $(`.saved_text ${collection_id}`).text()
        var saveElement = document.getElementById(`save_btn ${collection_id} ${post_id}`);
            
        real_url = url.replace('0', post_id).replace('1000', collection_id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: real_url,
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                'post_id': post_id,
                'collection_id': collection_id,


            },
            success: function(response){
                if (saveElement.classList.contains("saved")){
                    
                    saveElement.classList.remove("saved")
                    $(`.saved_text${collection_id}`).text('Save')

                } else if (!saveElement.classList.contains("saved")) {
                        
                    saveElement.classList.add("saved")
                        $(`.saved_text${collection_id}`).text('Saved')
                    }


                console.log(post_id)

                    
                },
                error: function(response){
                    console.log('error', response)
                }
            })

        })



    });
```

Comment: Have you checked that `.collection_save_form` is found? People will be more willing to help if you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi , your form are dynamically generated so can you change this `$('.collection_save_form').submit(function(e){` to `$(document).on("submit",".collection_save_form",function(){ //your codes ..})` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone with a similar problem: i solved this by putting an onclick event in the html that is generated by javascript